# How to check postfix server using telnet

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, telnet, aptitude

I have postfix email server on Ubuntu 11.04 version. I upgraded installed packages using the following command

```
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

Once I update those packages, I couldn't connect my email from my client machine. So I tested my postfix server using telnet.

```
telnet mail.mydomain.com 25
```

I got the following result for the above command.

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to mail.mydomain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I am very new to this postfix server. I couldn't understand whether my postfix server corrupted or not? Why I couldn't connect my email after updating the packages?

Answer (score 15):

Google "check email server using telnet" no quotes

Some of your output may vary but if you do not get any errors and you receive the email from the email server you can know that emial is flowing properly.

Also im not 100% sure if this answers your qestion however this is the way the check your email server form command line.

Also when using telnet be careful as 1 typo means you have start all over again.

From the port25 website

Here are all the commands I have bolded the command you will need to type out vs the output you will see.

**telnet mail.port25.com 25**

Trying 69.63.149.30...

Connected to mail.port25.com (69.63.149.30).

Escape character is '^]'.

220 mail.port25.com (PowerMTA(TM) v4.0) ESMTP service ready

**EHLO server.example.com**

250-mail.port25.com says hello

250-STARTTLS

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-PIPELINING

250-CHUNKING

250-8BITMIME

250-XACK

250-XMRG

250-SIZE 54525952

250-VERP

250 DSN

**MAIL FROM: <support@port25.com>**

250 2.1.0 MAIL ok

**RCPT TO: <support@port25.com>**

250 2.1.5 <support@port25.com> ok

**DATA**

354 send message

**From: "John Smith" <jsmith@port25.com>**

**To: "Jane Doe" <jdoe@port25.com>**

**Subject: test message sent from manual telnet session**

**Hello World,**

**.**

250 2.6.0 message received

**QUIT**

221 2.0.0 mail.port25.com says goodbye