# Postfix forwarding [open relay]

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

Good day to you all.
Today, I was setting up postfix on my CentOS 7 vps.

### What I want

I would like my server/postfix act according to the following rules:

1. Everyone on the planet should be able to mail `foo@server.com`
2. Postfix must forward this mail to `bar@externalmail.com`
3. Nothing else may get sent to any domain

For simplicity, I call my domain `server.com`.

### What I have

Right now,
I can send mails to `foo@server.com`, which do get forwarded to `bar@externalmail.com` (tested via telnet like [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/812511/how-to-check-postfix-server-using-telnet)). All DNS records are set correctly, SSL certificates are working well.

### My problem

I noticed I can send mails to any domains I want by connecting through telnet.

Sadly, spambots noticed this too, as I got a number of unknown connections, according to my `/var/log/maillog`. I checked some ip adresses via [an online blacklist checker](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) and all were blacklisted.

I am experienced (enough) in Linux systems, but very new to setting up postfix servers according to my wishes. Right now, I just blocked port 25 in ufw to stop the bots, until the problem is solved.

### Question

How can one setup postfix to forward only mails with specific receivers (`foo@server.com`) to specific forward adresses (`bar@externalmail.com`)?

Secondly, how can one block ip adresses which are blocked on lists as spamhaus and CBL?

### Configs

Here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf (adapted to question, excluding comments):

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
###################################
# My stuff
###################################
# Host and site name.
myhostname = server.com
mydomain = server.com
myorigin = server.com
# Virtual aliases.
virtual_alias_domains = server.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/privkey.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.com/privkey.pem
```

And here is my /etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

The last file which I think could be important is /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
foo@server.com bar@externalmail.com
```

#### A last word

The configs I have are all assembled from whatever I could find on the internet I thought was useful to achieve what I want postfix to do. I am very new in this postfix-setup-world, and must say it is one tough nut to crack. If you find anything wrong in my configs, please post a comment!

### Edit

Today, I configured Postfix with some restrictions. These restrictions seem to fix my problem and enforce the behaviour I want. Here are the new relevant parts in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
###################################
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    reject_unknown_client

###################################
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_unknown_hostname

###################################
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_address,
    reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
    reject_unknown_client_hostname

###################################
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unauth_destination
```

After finding more information about blocking, I created a new configuration.
This one is made to block all `unknown[ipv4]` connections from sending mail.

Also, it blocks attempts to send mail outside my domain, `server.com`.

I tested with [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx) open relay tool to see if it works, and it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For relay control, use `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, such as:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

Use `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` for spam control, for example:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
```

Required reading:

http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html

Comment: I've updated my question. Could you look at it for a second?

Comment: Regarding Edit 1, that seems fine, though the documentation recommends to include relay settings in smtpd_relay_restrictions. About Edit 2, yes, that's normal and probably unavoidable, so don't worry about it.