# How to test whether unknown user sent mail in postfix?

Tags: linux, postfix

Good day to you all,

today, I was setting up a postfix mail server. Everything works well: mails get forwarded from my server's mail address, `me@server.com`, to my personal email `personal@external.com`.

When testing with telnet, [like this](https://serverfault.com/questions/812511/how-to-check-postfix-server-using-telnet), I found that I could send mail only to `me@server.com`.

#### The problem

The thing is: My logs show me that I get connections from 'unknown'.
Here is a part of my `/var/log/maillog` (default CentOS postfix log location. On other Linux systems possibly `/var/log/mail.log`):

```
Jun  2 22:58:31 vps postfix/smtpd[23587]: connect from unknown[A.B.C.D]
Jun  2 22:58:31 vps postfix/smtpd[23585]: connect from unknown[A.B.C.E]
Jun  2 22:58:43 vps postfix/smtpd[23592]: connect from unknown[A.B.F.G]
Jun  2 22:58:55 vps postfix/smtpd[23597]: connect from unknown[A.B.F.H]
Jun  2 22:58:58 vps postfix/smtpd[23587]: disconnect from unknown[A.B.C.D]
...
```

With my current ruleset, these unknown spambots should be completely unable to send their garbage on their way to the internet.

However, I would like to check if these unknowns actually got any mail sent from my server.

#### What I tried

I tried the `mailq` command to check queued mails. This list was empty. However, this does not exclude that there *was* traffic.
Also, I checked my log with `cat /var/log/maillog | grep 'sent'`. Zero matches. I am uncertain whether this means no bot could send spam or that postfix does not log sent mails from unknown's.

#### The Question

How can one check outgoing mail traffic with postfix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any mail was sent, it would be in the log.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, I suppose that ultimately you want to block unknown users sending email via your postfix server.

For that you need to tighten up your "smtpd restrictions" in your /etc/postfix/main.cf file

Here is a sample that you can use ...

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    reject_unknown_client_hostname,
    permit

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
```

More info at:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/block-email-spam-postfix
http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists

Comment: Thanks for your information! I would quite like it if no 'unknown' bots/people could connect. Currently, I have setup a config which contain your suggested client restrictions. However, unknowns can still establish connections. Maybe `reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname` does the trick

Comment: Share your main.cf pls if you still have issues ...